# Does a `rel=canonical` Tag send any relevancy signals to the duplicate content's Category Page?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, canonical-url, site-structure, link-structure

> Below is a variation to my other [question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/115032/will-product-pages-help-create-context-for-their-respective-parent-categories-d) about `rel=canonical`.

I am working on an eCommerce site, which sells Canvas Prints.  Each Canvas Print is available in a variety of ways.  As such, every product has its own variant product.

I am thinking of creating Product Categories for each Product Variation and then optimise each Product Variation for its respective variant Keyword.  I would implement a `rel=canonical` Tag to deal with the issue of duplicate content.

If I did this, would the duplicate Product Page send any relevancy signals to its Product Category, as to help it rank for its Variant, whilst simultaneously, sending all of its Backlink Juice to the Primary Product?

The below is my though process:

**The Scenario:**

Each Canvas Print is available:

- As a 3 Piece;
- Framed or Unframed;
- Gallery Wrapped;
- Stretched;
- Large Print.

As such, each Product Page has a series of Drop Down menus, allowing the potential customer to choose their desired variations and/or add ons.

Assuming the Product is `'This is a Rose' Canvas Print`, they would find this Print within:

`Canvas Prints > Floral & Botanical > This is a Rose`

where they can then make their relevant selections.

**The Concern:**

After carrying out relevant Keyword Research, I have found that there is sufficient traffic for each of the above Variations.  Traffic, for Keywords, such as:

- Large Canvas Prints;
- Gallery Wrapped Canvas Art;
- Framed Canvas Paintings;
- 3 Piece Canvas Prints.

Since the website's Products would all match the above, I would naturally want to target such Keywords.

The problem is, it is not possible to include all of the above Keywords within areas, such as:

- URLs;
- Product Titles;

As a result, I feel this would result in missed opportunities in optimising for such Keywords.

I know that I would be able to add the Keywords to:

- Product Descriptions;
- Alt Tags;
- `<h2>` Tags etc.

But I feel I would be at a disadvantage to those who have dedicated Category Pages.  Would I be right in thinking this?

As such, I am thinking of creating a Site Structure, which looks a little something like:

[image]

**Duplicate Content:**

As you can see, each Category would have the same Product A and Product B, just each one tweaked for their respective Product Categories.  Examples of Product Title variations, would be:

- Framed 'This is a Rose' Canvas Print;
- Large 'This is a Rose' Canvas Print;
- Gallery Wrapped 'This is a Rose' Canvas Print.

To eliminate the issue of duplicate content, I would then implement a `rel=canonical` Tag as to point to the original Product, within the `Floral & Botanical` Product Category.

Has anyone found themselves within a similar situation?  I would appreciate any guidance on how to deal with this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your initial question: 'Does a `rel=canonical` Tag send any relevancy signals to the duplicate content's Category Page?' I don't know, probably not.

I think you are over thinking all this, you have category pages that are relevant for these variants, I wouldn't be worrying much about the products linked from these pages having to support them like this.

You seem to want to create individual product pages for these 6 variants, but then canonical them all back to 1 of them.  However, unless this is how your CMS already works, I wouldnt spend time implementing it like this, it seems kind of pointless.

Many eCommerce sites that have PDPs in more than one category, just use a single PDP URL page that is then linked from each category.

Comment: Let's say I have a 'Rose Canvas Print'.  This is available as a 3 Piece, 4 Piece and 5 Piece Canvas Print.  It has the URL `www.example.com/product/rose-canvas-print`.  Are you suggesting to place this Product within all of the Product Categories rather than creating multiple Product Pages?  My reservation is the fact that I could not optimise the Product Title for each Product Category.  Also, I would be forced to choose whether to display a 1 piece, 2 piece or 3 piece Product Image, to be displayed in each Product Category.  Am I right here or am I overlooking something?

Comment: You said you would be using a canonical tag on the multiple product pages, pointing back to just 1 single product URL right? If that's the case, then it doesn't matter if the canonicalised product pages have different titles, they wont have any effect as they are canonicalised to a different URL, they will be removed fromm the SERPS eventually and wont rank independently

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand that the duplicate product would eventually be removed from the index. I was thinking of creating such duplicate page so that when a visitor searches for a '3 Piece Canvas Print' they would land on the '3 Piece Canvas Print' Category Page which shows the 3 Piece Variants with the relevant product image and titles. The same with if a user searches for a 'Framed Canvas Print', they would land see the Framed variants. I was looking to canonicalise in order to prevent 'splitting the votes' whilst still able to populate each Category to help Category pages rank.

Comment: Carry on like that then.